# How to chain streams in await pipeline then set data in a map object?

Tags: node.js, typescript, stream, node-streams

I currently have the code below that works.

But to do it more "cleanly" I would like the set of the map object to be in the pipeline.
I've tried some things with [reduce()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v19.x/api/stream.html#readablereducefn-initial-options) but I'm afraid I don't quite understand its usage.

Any ideas how could I do this?

Thanks :)

Code that works :

```
  const reportData = new Map<number, CsvReportData>();
  const csvParser = parse({ delimiter: ',',
    cast: (value, context) => {
      if (context.column !== 'day') return Number(value);
      return value;
    },
    columns: ['xxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx'] });
  csvParser.on('data', (row: CsvReportRow) => {
    reportData.set(row.id, row as CsvReportData);
  });
  await pipeline(
    await report.download(reportId),
    csvParser
  );
```

Example that what I expect (obviously, it dont works) :

```
  const reportData = new Map<number, CsvReportData>();
  const csvParser = parse({ delimiter: ',',
    cast: (value, context) => {
      if (context.column !== 'day') return Number(value);
      return value;
    },
    columns: ['xxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx'] });
  csvParser.on('data', (row: CsvReportRow) => {
    reportData.set(row.id, row as CsvReportData);
  });
  await pipeline(
    await report.download(reportId),
    csvParser,
      .on('data', (row: CsvReportRow) => {
    reportData.set(row.id, row as CsvReportData);
  );
```

After searching, the `csv` package that I use has a `transform` method which allows me to answer my problem like this:

```
      const setReportData = transform((row: CsvReportRow) => {
        reportData.set(row.id, row as CsvReportData);
      });
```

But I'm still looking for an examples with stream reduce ^^